# Flickering Monitor

Tags: display, crt

My CRT Monitor is flickering frequently. Can it be cured. Where can i approach for this issue.
To Computer Repairing Person or TV repairing person. Is it possible to do it myself as i did in CPU issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the refresh rate is worth a shot. If you're in Windows XP, right click on the desktop, choose *Properties*, click the *Settings* tab, click the *Advanced* button, then there should be a Monitor tab, click it and there's a Screen Refresh rate. Different Windows OSes have it in similar places. It's been a while since I had a CRT but I'd typically set it as high as I could while still having the picture look good, 120hz I think.

Answer (score 2):

Try to De-Gauss it. Somewhere in the menu items for the monitor (is there a menu button actually on the monitor?) it should offer to do this.

What about the refresh rate from the computer? Try to alter that in graphics properties (what OS?) Any change?

Also, is it a new issue?

Comment: No change even after degaussing..